# While running the sample test using Bobcat AEM BDD framework , Steps are skipping and browser is also not launching

Tags: maven, github, cucumber, adobe, aem

While running the sample test using Bobcat AEM BDD framework to test author instance of AEM , Steps are skipping and browser is also not launching.

I have included glue in runner and also added required dependency.

I have taken refrence from this site : https://github.com/Cognifide/bobcat-archetype-aem-bdd

Maven : 3.5.2
JDK - 1.8

Also have changed instance and webdriver properties as per instruction given

I am new to Bobcat AEM BDD. Kindly help.

Please find Console Screenshot when I run the test : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXjRo.png)

Regards,
Kaveri

Comment: Hi, what happens when you try running a test? Are there any errors in the console? Stack traces?

Comment: @Kaveri Could you show your test suite please?

Comment: When I run Test Steps are getting skipped and browser doesn't launch.

Comment: @Kaveri: if the browser doesn't launch, then its probably issue with web driver.